# How to pass hex string color from .aspx to .ashx

Tags: c#, asp.net, hex, ashx

How do i pass hex string value to my .ashx page, where i need it in System.Drawing.Color

If i pass a normal string like:

```
string name="John"
```

Everything works fine.

But if i try to pass hex value like:

```
string bg_color ="#000000"
```

the string on .ashx page is empty or " "

Already tried passing only values without  #, which actually works. But if i add # later like:

```
Color _bgClr = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(string.Format{"#{0}", text_background_color);
```

I get error of **# is invalid parameter** when i try to change HEX(background  values) on my webform.

Any clues?

Please help

**UPDATE**

```
<img class="link-realtime1" src="ImageGen.ashx?bo=<%=inp_barva_ozadja.Text %>&bt=<%=inp_barva_teksta.Text %>" style="float: left;margin-top: -20px;"/>
```

**UPDATE2 - .aspx**

```
<form id="image_generator" runat="server">
<div class="main">
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="options" style="float: left;width: 50%;">
            <label>
                <span>Širina</span>
                <asp:TextBox ID="inp_sirina" Width="125" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </label><span style="color:red"><asp:Literal ID="napaka_s" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span><br />
            <label>
                <span>Višina</span>
                <asp:TextBox ID="inp_visina" Width="125" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </label><span style="color:red"><asp:Literal ID="napaka_v" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span><br />
            <label>
                <span>Tekst</span>
                <asp:TextBox ID="inp_text" Width="125" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </label><span style="color:red"><asp:Literal ID="napaka_t" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span><br />      
            <label>
                <span>Velikost pisave</span>
                <asp:TextBox ID="inp_velikost" Width="125px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </label><span style="color:red"><asp:Literal ID="napaka_vp" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span><br />           
            <label>
                <span>Barva ozadja</span>
                <asp:TextBox ID="inp_barva_ozadja" Width="125px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </label><span style="color:red"><asp:Literal ID="napaka_bo" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span><br />
           <label>
                <span>Barva teksta</span>
                <asp:TextBox ID="inp_barva_teksta" Width="125px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </label><span style="color:red"><asp:Literal ID="napaka_bt" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span><br />
            <div id="colorpicker"></div><br />
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#colorpicker').farbtastic('#inp_barva_ozadja');
                });
           </script>
            <a class="link-realtime" href="ImageGen.ashx?w=<%= inp_sirina.Text %>&h=<%= inp_visina.Text %>&t=<%= inp_text.Text %>&ts=<%= inp_velikost.Text %>&bg=<%= inp_barva_ozadja.Text %>&tc=<%= inp_barva_teksta.Text %>">Generiraj sliko</a><br />       
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#inp_sirina, #inp_visina, #inp_barva_ozadja, #inp_barva_teksta, #inp_text, #inp_velikost').keyup(function () {
            var tekst1 = $('#inp_sirina').val();
            var tekst2 = $('#inp_visina').val();
            var tekst3 = $('#inp_text').val();
            var v_pisave = $('#inp_velikost').val();
            var barva1 = $('#inp_barva_ozadja').val();
            var barva2 = $('#inp_barva_teksta').val();;
            var path = "ImageGen.ashx?w=" + tekst1 + "&h=" + tekst2 + "&t=" + tekst3 + "&ts=" + v_pisave + "&bg=" + barva1 + "&tc=" + barva2;       
            $("a.link-realtime").attr("href", path);    
            $("img.link-realtime1").attr("src", path);
            });
        </script>                  
        <div id="output">
            <span class="output-result"></span></br>
            <img class="link-realtime1" src="ImageGen.ashx?w=<%= inp_sirina.Text %>&h=<%= inp_visina.Text %>&t=<%= inp_text.Text %>&ts=<%= inp_velikost.Text %>&bo=<%=inp_barva_ozadja.Text %>&bt=<%=inp_barva_teksta.Text %>" style="float: left;margin-top: -20px;"/>
        </div></br>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

**UPDATE3 - .ashx**

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        string _width = context.Request.QueryString["w"];
        int __width = Convert.ToInt32(_width);
        string _height = context.Request.QueryString["h"];
        int __height = Convert.ToInt32(_height);
        string text = context.Request.QueryString["t"];
        string text_size = context.Request.QueryString["ts"];
        int _text_size = Convert.ToInt32(text_size);
        /*string text_background_color = context.Request.QueryString["bo"];*/
        string text_background_color = "#000000";
        Color _bgClr = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(text_background_color);
        /*Color _bgClr = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(string.Format("{0}", "#" + text_background_color));*/
        /*string text_color = context.Request.QueryString["bt"];*/
        string text_color = "#FFFFFF";
        Color _txtClr = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(text_color);

        Bitmap slika = new Bitmap(1, 1);

        float koordinataX = (__width / 2) - (((__width / 2) / 2) / 2);
        float koordinataY = (__height / 2);

        if (koordinataX < 50)
        {
            _text_size = _text_size / 2;
        }

        text = Regex.Replace(text, "(.{" + 20 + "})", "$1" + Environment.NewLine);

        Font pisava = new Font("Verdana", _text_size, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);

        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(slika);

        slika = new Bitmap(slika, new Size(__width, __height));

        graphics = Graphics.FromImage(slika);
        graphics.Clear(_bgClr);
        graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;

        using (var sf = new StringFormat()
        {
            Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
            LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        })
        {
            graphics.DrawString(text, pisava, new SolidBrush(_txtClr), new Rectangle(0, 0, slika.Width, slika.Height), sf);
        }

        /*graphics.DrawString(text, pisava, new SolidBrush(_txtClr), koordinataX, koordinataY);*/

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        slika.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);

        byte[] bajt = ms.ToArray();

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(bajt);
        context.Response.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried url encoding passing parameter `bg_color` to .ashx?

Comment: if url encoding is different to what i've done (see update), can you please poste example on my form @BobDust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `string.Format` code is not correct. Should be

```
string.Format("{0}", "#" + text_background_color)
```

But you can do without.

```
string text_background_color = "FF00FC";

Color _bgClr = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" + text_background_color);
```

**UPDATE**

You are converting the QueryString Parameters without checking for NULL values, so if one or more QueryString is not present or empty, your code will fail. It has nothing to do with setting the color.

```
string _width = context.Request.QueryString["w"];
string _height = context.Request.QueryString["h"];
string text = context.Request.QueryString["t"];
string text_size = context.Request.QueryString["ts"];
string text_background_color = context.Request.QueryString["bg"];
int __width = 300;
int __height = 200;      
int __text_size = 10;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_width))
{
    __width = Convert.ToInt32(_width);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_height))
{
    __height = Convert.ToInt32(_height);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text_size))
{
    __text_size = Convert.ToInt32(text_size);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text_background_color))
{
    text_background_color = "#" + text_background_color;
}
else
{
    text_background_color = "#000000";
}
```

Comment: strange, all of you seem to suggest that. and yes while it probably should work, i get this error = Additional information: # is not a valid value for Int32.

This doesn't happen when the page loads and has default value of 000000, only happens when i try to change it manually to ffffff or any other

Comment: Int32 error? Where and how are you using `_bgClr`? And what do you mean by  `change it manually`? The problem is probably somehere else in your code.

Comment: I have a web form that has 6 different textboxes (width, heigh, text, font size, background color and text color)...whole form has default values behind code...now user can type his own values and generate desired image...i get all of the user values (width, heigh, text, font size) except for background color and text color...which means image creates as user wants it, but doesn't change colors

Comment: You'll have to post more code, with the current snippet this is impossible to solve. What does the code in the ashx file look like?

Comment: just updated all the code. some of the code is commented as im trying different things (specially in .ashx)

Comment: to make it a little easier for you = inp_barva_ozadja = background color, inp_barva_teksta = text color. would translate it all to english, but would just take too much time

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: holy hell. been working on it for 3 days, and you fixed it for me! thank you so so much!

Comment: seems like such a simple solution that i just couldn't figure out

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple url encoding for the value of parameter `bg_color` like this:

```
<img class="link-realtime1" src="ImageGen.ashx?w=<%= inp_sirina.Text %>&h=<%= inp_visina.Text %>&t=<%= inp_text.Text %>&ts=<%= inp_velikost.Text %>&bo=<%=inp_barva_ozadja.Text %>&bt=<%=inp_barva_teksta.Text %>&bg_color=<%=HttpUtility.UrlEncode("#000000") %>" style="float: left;margin-top: -20px;"/>
```

can be retrieved in the generic handler as below:

```
var bgColor = context.Request.QueryString["bg_color"];
```

Comment: but this will only work on pre-assigned value of #000000, won't it? Means that online on form, user won't be possible to change it to whatever he wants. or am i wrong?

Comment: Yep, this answer focuses on passing parameters. For passing values entered by user, you need to read those from the color picker `inp_barva_ozadja`.